# javascript string.replace question

Tags: javascript, replace, global

I know you can do something like this:

```
var str = "Microsoft has the largest capital reserves of any tech company. Microsoft is located in California.";
str = str.replace(/microsoft/gi, "Apple");
```

and you'd get the following: Apple has the largest capital reserves of any tech company. Apple is located in California.

How can I use the global case insensitive to change a string like 07/08/2011 to 07082011?

I tried variations of str.replace(///gi, "") with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var input = "07/08/2011";
var output = input.replace(/\//g,""); //output 07082011
```

Answer (score 0):

try using **escape character** (back slash):

```
str.replace(/\//gi, "")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str = str.replace(/\//g,'')
```

this will remove all forward slashes

Comment: is unnecessary the "i" in this case.